# How to add an item to a drop down list in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I want to add the "Add new" at a specific index, but I am not sure of the syntax. I have the following code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        DRPFill();
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DropDownList1.Items.Add("Add New");
        }
}
public void DRPFill()
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //Object
        AddMajor objMajor = new AddMajor();

        //Data Table
        DataTable dtMajor = objMajor.find();

        //Data Source
        DropDownList1.DataSource = dtMajor;
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "MajorID";
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "MajorName";

        //Data Bind
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: DropDownList1.Items.Insert?

Comment: Why the check in `DRPFill` method ? , why not put that in the `if` of the page load

Answer (score 62):

Try this, it will insert the list item at index 0;

```
DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Add New", ""));
```

Comment: ddl.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Select Crusher", "0")) is giving me this error - BC30516: Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' accepts this number of arguments.

Answer (score 39):

Which specific index? If you want 'Add New' to be first on the dropdownlist you can add it though the code like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server">
     <asp:ListItem Text="Add New" Value="0" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

If you want to add it at a different index, maybe the last then try:

```
ListItem lst = new ListItem ( "Add New" , "0" );

DropDownList1.Items.Insert( DropDownList1.Items.Count-1 ,lst);
```

Comment: As far as I know there's no Dropdownlist1.Add method. It would be DropdownList1.Items.Add() and the OP did mention a specific index which you'd still need to know as the Add method will just add it without caring about the index.

Answer (score 9):

Try following code;

```
DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(txt_box1.Text));
```