# How to update column of database where id of column is equal to dropdownlist1.items

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have page in asp.net Website. My database has table with 3 columns.

[image]

I Have GridView with Checkbox within it

I want for each row in Grid View rows when checked of CheckBox1 is true then return id of rows in DropDownList1. This code done it successfully:

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (((CheckBox)gvr.FindControl("CheckBox1")).Checked == true)
            {
                string data;
                data = gvr.Cells[0].Text;
                DropDownList1.Items.Add(data);
            }
}
```

> The problem is that I want to update state_p columns in my database to
>   “1” WHERE id= '" + DropDownList1.Items + "'.

for e.g:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String searchstr = String.Format("SELECT * From mytable WHERE id='" + Dropdownlist1.items + "'");
            SqlDataReader dr = findrecords(searchstr);
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                string updatestr = string.Format(" update mytable " +
                                                 "set state_p=N'{0}'" +
                                                 " WHERE id={1}",
                                                 1, Dropdownlist1.items);

                int result = updatedb(updatestr);
                if (result > 0)
                {

                    lbl_error.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                    lbl_error.Text = "ok";
                    GridView1.DataBind();

                }
                else
                {
                    lbl_error.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    lbl_error.Text = "  ";
                    GridView1.DataSource = null;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lbl_error.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                lbl_error.Text = "no records exist";
            }
    }
```

How can I do that. Please help me.`**

Answer (score 1):

You must set ***data*** and ***value*** in DropDownList with following code for example:

```
using System.Collections.Generics;
...
List<ListItem> items = new List<ListItem>();
items.Add(new ListItem("Item 2", "Value 2"));
items.Add(new ListItem("Item 1", "Value 1"));
items.Add(new ListItem("Item 3", "Value 3"));
items.Sort(delegate(ListItem item1, ListItem item2) 
{ return item1.Text.CompareTo(item2.Text); });
dropdown.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray());
```

and for get value from DropDownList is selected :

```
var i = myDropDown.SelectedValue;
```

finish:

```
where id = i;
```

Example for Add:

[How to add an item to a drop down list in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468956/how-to-add-an-item-to-a-drop-down-list-in-asp-net)

Example for Get:

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/484535/howplustoplusdisplayplusselectedplusvaluesplusfrom

I hope this help you.